White rectangle on the screen when resuming from screen off
I have an Acer Swift 3 (Intel Core i3-8250U and Nvidia MX150) with Ubuntu 24.10 installed on it. I use the nvidia-driver 560.35.03 which are the recommended ones.
I noticed that when the PC is running with the screen turned off (lid closed or simply pressing the button to turn it off and lid open) and then I turn it on, there is a white rectangle around the display that remains there for a while, even if I restart the PC to another system. (something like this )

I tried installing a Windows 11 instance to see if it has the same behavior, so I tried turning off the screen while Windows 11 was working and after a while turning it back on. The problem didn't appear. I also tried it while running the BIOS, and the problem does not occur.
If I use Ubuntu with the screen turned on for hours, the problem doesn't appear either.
I am wondering how can Ubuntu affect my display's hardware in this way? Has anyone ever noticed something similar?

I believe the lighter rectangle is the start of an animation that ought to disappear in a few seconds. The animation may be broken. I don't think there is anything wrong with your hardware per se.

the problem is that even if I restart my pc the problem remains there.
